# SSL Web Service Exception Connection closed to child with abortive shutdown

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I am running into an error where the connection from my client server is apparently closing early for a reason that I do not know. I am hitting two different servers. On one server the data is coming back and it is working perfectly. On the other server my client gets the error:

Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: Connection reset

The error on the server says:

Connection closed to child with abortive shutdown.

I have checked the whitelist/blacklist and there should be no issue there and both servers use the same certificate, so it is not an issue with the trust store not having the cert. I have been told there is no difference between the two servers configuration, so I am unsure of why this is not working. If anybody has any ideas I would appreciate it.